# How do you find if the default Messenger app is open on Android?

Tags: java, android

Is there anyway that you can access that? I'm wanting to launch my application only if the Messenger is open. Is there anyway I can do this? I've been searching around and I can't seem to find anything. I've also looked on my phone and the Messenger doesn't show up in running applications.

And I'm wanting to be able to have a navigation bar slide from the left, but when it loads the layout there is a default white background. Is there anyway I can do away with this?

Comment: You're asking two completely unrelated questions. Please give more information about your use case for Messenger (and even which one you're asking about). It usually doesn't make logical sense to try this on Android; what if, for example, Android kills the app right after yours loads?

Comment: @chrylis The use for having access to the Messenger is to have the navigation bar available. Or a sliding drawer (I wasn't actually going to use the nav bar as a nav tool). It just fit the purpose of what I needed. The info it would contain is all current info on the Contact that you were texting. Allowing for you to change things or scribble a couple notes about their birthday or something of that nature. That was essentially my idea.

Answer (score 1):

There is no single "default Messenger app". Device manufacturers and ROM modders can and do ship other SMS clients as their "default". Users can install third-party SMS clients and, as of Android 4.4, designate them as the "default". Then, there are the devices that do not have telephony capability and will have no SMS clients. Then, there are restricted profiles in Android 4.3+, where even though the device might have one or more SMS clients, the current user does not.

In short, I suggest that you take another approach.